# Angular with ngrx - nothig happen

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have problem. Currently i learn NgRx from scratch. I create angular project, add new car component. Next add ngrx state, actions, reducer and effects. When i run my project, i don't have aby error, though set  wrong API url, when i set correct url,  still notting happen.

When i add console log to reducer, i see this in console. But when i add console log, to car.effects.ts with message true, then not showing.

My app code:
Reducer

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as CarActions from './car.actions';
import { Car } from 'src/models/car.model';

const initialState: Car = {
   brand: '',
   model: ''
};

export function carReducer(state: Car[] = [initialState], action: CarActions.Actions) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case CarActions.ADD_CAR:
            return [...state, action.payload];
        case CarActions.ADD_CAR_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                carError: action.payload,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

State

```
import { Car } from './../../models/car.model';

export interface AppState {
  readonly car: Car;
}
```

Actions

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Car } from './../../models/car.model';

export const ADD_CAR       = '[CAR] Add';
export const ADD_CAR_FAIL    = '[CAR] Fail';

export class AddCar implements Action {
    readonly type = ADD_CAR;

    constructor(public payload: Car) {}
}

export class AddCarFail implements Action {
    readonly type = ADD_CAR_FAIL;

    constructor(public payload: string) {}
}

export type Actions = AddCar | AddCarFail;
```

Effects

```
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import * as CarActions from './car.actions';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { switchMap, catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CarEffects {
    @Effect()
    carAdd = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(CarActions.ADD_CAR),
        switchMap((carData: CarActions.AddCar) => {
            console.log('true');
            return this.http.post('http://myapi.com/api', { brand: carData.payload.brand, model: carData.payload.model }).pipe(map(resData => {
                localStorage.setItem('test', 'asdasdasd');
            }),
                catchError(errorRes => {
                    console.log(errorRes);
                    const errorMessage = 'An unknown error occurred!';
                    if (!errorRes.error || !errorRes.error.error) {
                        return of(new CarActions.AddCarFail(errorMessage));
                    }

                    console.log(errorRes.error.error.message);
                    return of(new CarActions.AddCarFail(errorRes.error.error.message));
                }));
        })
    );

    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

App.Module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CarComponent } from './car/car.component';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { carReducer } from './car/car.reducer';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({car: carReducer}),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I install store-devtools and i have in console:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/config.d.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Sebastian/Documents/ngrx-angular/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'.
node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/devtools.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Sebastian/Documents/ngrx-angular/node_modules/@ngrx/store/store"' has no exported member 'Dispatcher'.
node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/devtools.d.ts(1,22): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Sebastian/Documents/ngrx-angular/node_modules/@ngrx/store/store"' has no exported member 'Reducer'.
node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/extension.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Sebastian/Documents/ngrx-angular/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'.
node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/instrument.d.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Sebastian/Documents/ngrx-angular/node_modules/@ngrx/store/store"' has no exported member 'Reducer'.
```

Comment: Install store dev tool to see if there any change from the store

Comment: @TonyNgo i install this tools and add console output to my question.

Comment: Can you update your code to https://stackblitz.com or github ?

Comment: @TonyNgo https://github.com/PawelCyrklaf/angular-ngrx :)

Comment: Ok i got your source code. Wil get back to you ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some small modify. You are using wrong version

```
{
  "name": "ngrx-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^7.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Also change here

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ car: carReducer }),
    HttpClientModule,
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 5
    })
  ],
```

The result

[image]

The pr [here](https://github.com/PawelCyrklaf/angular-ngrx/pull/2)

Comment: Now works, but i have question. Why my effects not working? I have post request, to wrong url and many console log, but i don't see result. I wanted to do this so that the request would follow post as effects, but on the principle that in the case of a successful request it displays ok in the console, in the case of an error it shows an error. I have written effects, but it does not work from what I see.

Comment: I think it's of topic you can create another question and I can take a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57270283/my-ngrx-effects-not-working-notting-happend

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all your packages are using the latest version, and that the version differences aren't breaking. I recently encountered this problem as well and the problem seemed to be that the wrong version was installed. I was using Angular 10, and used the command below to install the store:

```
npm install @ngrx/store --save
```

My package.json was updated with an old version of the store, but effects and devtools correctly installed with the latest versions:

```
"@ngrx/effects": "^9.2.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^1.5.0",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^9.2.0",
```

The solution to this problem is to manually update the versions and run npm install, or to run the install again with @latest attached to the end:

```
npm install @ngrx/store@latest
```

After this, all packages were installed correctly.

```
"@ngrx/effects": "^9.2.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^9.2.0",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^9.2.0",
```

This also fixes the issue of not being able to import **StoreModule** in your **app.module.ts**:

```
Module '"../../node_modules/@ngrx/store/store"' has no exported member 'StoreModule'.
```