# My NgRx effects not working, nothing happend

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have problem with my NgRx effects.

The application correctly adds to the store, unfortunately my effects with the request are not performed, i.e. at the time of launching the addition of a new car, add it to the store and that's it. The problem is that there are no console logs from my effects, no http error because of the wrong url, nothing at all.

My app code:

Reducer

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as CarActions from './car.actions';
import { Car } from 'src/models/car.model';

const initialState: Car = {
   brand: '',
   model: ''
};

export function carReducer(state: Car[] = [initialState], action: CarActions.Actions) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case CarActions.ADD_CAR:
            return [...state, action.payload];
        case CarActions.ADD_CAR_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                carError: action.payload,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

State

```
import { Car } from './../../models/car.model';

export interface AppState {
  readonly car: Car;
}
```

Actions

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Car } from './../../models/car.model';

export const ADD_CAR       = '[CAR] Add';
export const ADD_CAR_FAIL    = '[CAR] Fail';

export class AddCar implements Action {
    readonly type = ADD_CAR;

    constructor(public payload: Car) {}
}

export class AddCarFail implements Action {
    readonly type = ADD_CAR_FAIL;

    constructor(public payload: string) {}
}

export type Actions = AddCar | AddCarFail;
```

Effects

```
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import * as CarActions from './car.actions';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { switchMap, catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CarEffects {
    @Effect()
    carAdd = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(CarActions.ADD_CAR),
        switchMap((carData: CarActions.AddCar) => {
            console.log('true');
            return this.http.post('http://myapi.com/api', { brand: carData.payload.brand, model: carData.payload.model }).pipe(map(resData => {
                localStorage.setItem('test', 'asdasdasd');
            }),
                catchError(errorRes => {
                    console.log(errorRes);
                    const errorMessage = 'An unknown error occurred!';
                    if (!errorRes.error || !errorRes.error.error) {
                        return of(new CarActions.AddCarFail(errorMessage));
                    }

                    console.log(errorRes.error.error.message);
                    return of(new CarActions.AddCarFail(errorRes.error.error.message));
                }));
        })
    );

    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

App.Module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CarComponent } from './car/car.component';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { carReducer } from './car/car.reducer';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ car: carReducer }),
    HttpClientModule,
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 5
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And most importantly, does my code use NgRx in a good way?

Comment: return this.http.post('http://myapi.com/api', { brand: carData.payload.brand, model: carData.payload.model }).pipe(map(resData => {
                localStorage.setItem('test', 'asdasdasd');
            })
Try to use tap instead of map

Comment: @TonyNgo now works fine :) thank you for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not add Effect to your module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CarComponent } from './car/car.component';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { carReducer } from './car/car.reducer';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { CarEffects } from './car/car.effects';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ car: carReducer }),
    HttpClientModule,
    EffectsModule.forRoot([CarEffects]),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 5
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the `EffectsModule` to register your effects.

In the `app.module.ts`, you can do:

```
import {CarEffects} from 'path/to/careffects';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ car: carReducer }),
    HttpClientModule,
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 5
    }),
    //                               ADD THIS BELOW !!
    EffectsModule.forRoot(
      [CarEffects]
    )
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Your typing is definitely faster than me ;)